# Looking for accelerometer to control a relay

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am actually very new to DIY hardware projects and need help looking for accelerometer that can send signal to  my Arduino board when accelerometer state change from moving to stop OR stop to moving . Reason I want to do this is to save battery on my board. I want it to be running only when the accelerometer state is on move and if state changes to stop, board should run for a while and then go to sleep. I have following challenges to consider.

1. Accelerometer should consume a lot less battery as the whole purpose
   for this experiment is to save on battery.
2. Accelerometer has to be independent from the Board , just like a power management extension that will control the power to Arduino based on it's state.
3. Has to be cheap.

Any Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an external interrupt from your accelerometer.
So you have to pay attention that your sensor module provides such interrupt capabilities.
A good module can be for example the [Triple-Axis Accelerometer w/ I2C/SPI](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1231) (based on the ADXL chip) from Adafruit for $17.50.

In addition, you need a Arduino with interrupt pins. Most Arduinos have at least two interrupt pins (numbers 0 (on digital pin 2) and 1 (on digital pin 3)).

[PKMC](http://pkmc.uk.com/blogs/tutorials/15326309-arduino-interrupts-with-accelerometer-and-neopixels) structured the necessary steps for interrupting an Arduino with an accelerometer as follows:

1. Connect ADXL Interrupt Pin 1 to Arduino Pin 2 or Pin 3
2. Set accelerometer's parameters (e.g. )

```c
 //set ADXL interrupts
 //enable single tap interrupt
 //writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_INT_ENABLE, 0b01000000);

 //enable single and double tap interrupt
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_INT_ENABLE, 0b01100000);

 //map all interrupts to pin1
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_INT_MAP, 0b00000000);

 // single tap configuration
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_DUR, 0x1F); // 625us/LSB
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_THRESH_TAP, 48); 
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_TAP_AXES, 0b111); // enable tap detection on x,y,z axes

 //double tap configuration
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_LATENT, 0x50);
 writeRegister(ADXL345_REG_WINDOW, 0xff);
```

3. Assign Arduino INT0 (interrupt0) (or to INT1 (interrupt0) if you have choose Pin 3) in setup code

```c
attachInterrupt(0, accelInterrupt, RISING);
```

4. Write INT0 interrupt routine before main loop

```c
void accelInterrupt(){
    //...
}
```

and provides an [example](http://pkmc.uk.com/blogs/tutorials/15326309-arduino-interrupts-with-accelerometer-and-neopixels) (and the [code](https://github.com/blinkyblinky/accelerometer/blob/master/PKInterruptTutorialAccelerometerBlogPost.ino)) with an accelerometer and neopixels.

I am confident that the example can help you!

Comment: Can I use the analog pins for interrupt? I already have few other sensor attached to interrupt pins.

Comment: It depends on the external interrupt capabilities of your Arduino. Arduino Leonardos support additional external interrupts on Pin 0, 1, 7, while the Arduino Mega2560 have four additional external interrupts on Pin 18-21. Simply use a analog pin would probably not work (except this pin is a external interrupt pin, which is enabled).

Comment: How do I find out that accelerometer has the interrupt capability?